# Error copying file from directory to another directory of the internal storage of the phone?

Tags: java, android, file

How to copy/move?

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(file2.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/nio/file/Paths;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.nio.file.Paths` was added in API level 26 (which is Android 8.0, Oreo). The error you quote suggests that you tried to run that code on a device with a lower API level than that.